# SqlCommand AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username =  ? AND Password = ?", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

When I run the program I get

> Incorrect syntax near '?'.

On this line:

```
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Can anyone see what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: is the query being run on SQL Server.. and if so what version..? is  this just a standard Query or is this run against a StoredProcedure.. if it's a stored procedure.. change the "Username" to be "@Username" and "Password" to be "@Password"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username =  @Username AND Password = @Password", connection))
{
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
  using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while(reader.Read())
    {
      //do actual works
    }
  }
}
```

Improved with `using` keywords, which is not necessary, but recommended

Comment: Well worth adding... if ((reader.HasRows) && (reader.Read())) {   }

Comment: @Lloyd: Its not necessary.  If `reader.HasRows()` returns `false`, so will `reader.Read()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password",
    connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

You might want to read up on sql.

Comment: So... the @ sign is optional in the `AddWithValue`?

Comment: @JohnHenckel Yep. Works with or without.

Answer (score 1):

Which DBMS are you using? If you're using SQL Server, that is incorrect syntax for the query. You need:

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand(@"select * 
                     from users 
                     where username = @username and password = @password");

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
```